# Universal deep linking, does not launch the app

Tags: ios, objective-c, appdelegate, deep-linking

I have implemented universal deep linking in my app by following the following links:

https://blog.branch.io/how-to-setup-universal-links-to-deep-link-on-apple-ios-9

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/General/Conceptual/AppSearch/UniversalLinks.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40016308-CH12-SW1

Everything seems fine at both the ends (app and server). But the app is not getting launched at all if the URL is hit on the browser. I have handled the redirection in application's continueUserActivity delegate. But this would only work if the app gets launched first. Can someone clarify please what could be the possible reason?